# Automobile data including weight, engine output

Tags: data-request

Is there an open data set of car metrics? I'm looking to combine these with other data such as accidents, thefts, etc.

I imagine that these types of data are readily available within auto insurance companies to calculate rates, and I was hoping an open data set exists out there.

I'd like to find the following fields for each car:

- Manufacturer
- Model
- Country (at least Canada/USA)
- Release year
- Weight
- Drive (FWD, RWD, AWD, 4WD)
- number of doors
- number of passengers
- Engine displacement/cylinders
- Engine output

Comment: [Discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11172031/2327328) for similar question on Stackoverflow, mentioning [this dataset](https://github.com/n8barr/automotive-model-year-data)

Answer (score 3):

From 1985!

**UCI Machine Learning Repository - [Automobile Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Automobile)**

> This data set consists of three types of entities: (a) the specification of an auto in terms of various characteristics, (b) its assigned insurance risk rating, (c) its normalized losses in use as compared to other cars. The second rating corresponds to the degree to which the auto is more risky than its price indicates. Cars are initially assigned a risk factor symbol associated with its price. Then, if it is more risky (or less), this symbol is adjusted by moving it up (or down) the scale. Actuarians call this process "symboling". A value of +3 indicates that the auto is risky, -3 that it is probably pretty safe.
>
> The third factor is the relative average loss payment per insured vehicle year. This value is normalized for all autos within a particular size classification (two-door small, station wagons, sports/speciality, etc...), and represents the average loss per car per year.

Answer (score 3):

I used the [Edmunds API](http://developer.edmunds.com/) for a personal project and was able to query that to build out quite a variety of details about different make and models.  It seemed to be pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently closed a project in the vehicle field - for a fleet company. I can help with some of the data mentioned in the question. You can find the manufacturer, model, release year, weight (I guess kerb weight is what you need because there is also a parameter known as dry weight), number of passengers (seats available in the car), engine displacement/cylinders and output in this [free wiki database](https://www.auto-data.net/en/allbrands).

I have no idea if you look for vehicles for a specific car market; this link is mostly for the European cars (+ some cars for China/USA/Japan).